# power BI exclude Duplicate Row with condition

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns, calculated-field

```
I have this table
```

[image]

which is a live connection from ssas to power BI
I want to count duplicate based on `typeName` and wher `completeDate is blank`
I wrote the folowing DAX

```
Duplicate = VAR Dup = COUNTROWS(FILTER('Table',EARLIER('Table'[typeName])='Table'[typeName]))
RETURN
         CALCULATE(Dup,
            FILTER('Table', 'Table'[CompletedDate]=BLANK()))
```

The current Output

[image]

which is wrong
my desired output is to return `where completeDate is blank`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are actually constants. Does this work?

```
    Duplicate = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER('Table',
            EARLIER('Table'[typeName])='Table'[typeName]
            && 'Table'[CompletedDate]=BLANK()
        )
    )
)
```